# pureftpd mysql auth working on one server but not others with same config

Tags: mysql, login, ubuntu-16.04, pureftpd

**System:**
  Ubuntu 16.04
  Percona Server (using Galera cluster)
  pure-ftpd-mysql from the Ubuntu repositories

The pureftpd database is replicated to all five servers in the cluster and I have verified the replication is working and the tables are identical.

**Issue:**
I installed pure-ftpd-mysql on one of the five servers in our distributed cluster, and have it authenticating users correctly.

After installing pure-ftpd-mysql on each of the other servers I shut down pure-ftpd on each, deleted its folder in `/etc`, and used `scp -r /etc/pure-ftpd server/etc/pureftpd` to copy the working config files from the first server to the other four.

I can connect to the ftpd on each server, but I can only login on the first one. `VerboseLog` is set on each. Here is the syslog output from the workinh one and one of the non-workign ones:

**Working: host `hub`**

```
Jan 21 06:13:32 h0 pure-ftpd: (?@68.103.155.231) [INFO] New connection from 68.103.155.231
Jan 21 06:13:32 h0 pure-ftpd: (?@68.103.155.231) [DEBUG] Command [auth] [TLS]
Jan 21 06:13:32 h0 pure-ftpd: (?@68.103.155.231) [DEBUG] Command [auth] [SSL]
Jan 21 06:13:32 h0 pure-ftpd: (?@68.103.155.231) [DEBUG] Command [user] [test]
Jan 21 06:13:32 h0 pure-ftpd: (?@68.103.155.231) [DEBUG] Command [pass] [<*>]
Jan 21 06:13:32 h0 pure-ftpd: (?@68.103.155.231) [INFO] test is now logged in
Jan 21 06:13:32 h0 pure-ftpd: (test@68.103.155.231) [DEBUG] Command [opts] [UTF8 ON]
Jan 21 06:13:32 h0 pure-ftpd: (test@68.103.155.231) [DEBUG] Command [pwd] []
```

**Non-working: host `l1`**

```
Jan 21 06:15:28 l1 pure-ftpd: (?@68.103.155.231) [INFO] New connection from 68.103.155.231
Jan 21 06:15:28 l1 pure-ftpd: (?@68.103.155.231) [DEBUG] Command [auth] [TLS]
Jan 21 06:15:28 l1 pure-ftpd: (?@68.103.155.231) [DEBUG] Command [auth] [SSL]
Jan 21 06:15:28 l1 pure-ftpd: (?@68.103.155.231) [DEBUG] Command [user] [test]
Jan 21 06:15:28 l1 pure-ftpd: (?@68.103.155.231) [DEBUG] Command [pass] [<*>]
Jan 21 06:15:28 l1 pure-ftpd: (?@68.103.155.231) [INFO] PAM_RHOST enabled. Getting the peer address
Jan 21 06:15:34 l1 pure-ftpd: (?@68.103.155.231) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [test]
Jan 21 06:15:34 l1 pure-ftpd: (?@68.103.155.231) [INFO] Logout.
```

I have found limited information on the `PAM_RHOST` item and I kind of understand why it's happening, but I'm not sure how to get it shut off. Here is the current configuration:

```
AltLog
clf:/var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log

ChrootEveryone
yes

CreateHomeDir
yes

DontResolve
yes

FSCharset
UTF-8

MinUID
1000

MySQLConfigFile
/etc/pure-ftpd/db/mysql.conf

NoAnonymous
yes

PAMAuthentication
no

PureDB
/etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.pdb

TLSCipherSuite
ALL:!aNULL:!SSLv3

UnixAuthentication
no

VerboseLog
yes
```

At this point I'm at a loss as to why the configuration copied from the working server to the others is now allowing me to login. Looking for ideas and resources to find this answer...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing `pure-ftpd-mysql` and reinstalling

```
apt remove pure-ftpd-mysql
apt autoremove
apt install pure-ftpd-mysql
```